# Can AWS host a HLS link that can change at a whim?

Tags: amazon-web-services, http-live-streaming, apple-tv, roku, amazon-fire-tv

​Hi everyone,

**Situation:**  I want AWS to host a HLS link which I can change at a whim (so, not hard coded) to guide devices like the Roku, Fire TV, Alexa, Apple TV, where the HLS link is. Currently my programs tell devices to go to Ooyala then Ooyala tells the device where to get HLS link.
So, I want to cut out Ooyala and just use AWS to tell devices where to get the HLS link (at CDN).

**Problem:**  Does anyone know if it is possible or another solution? if so, what do I need and what to research? I was thinking something along the lines of writing a script and a static IP.

**If you have an idea, please label a few steps for me, so I can get an idea the possibilities!**

Thank you,

Jackson

Comment: We need a clearee definition of *"tell devices where to get the HLS link,"* I think.  If it's just a simple, unauthenticated `GET` request with a static response or redirect over HTTPS, then you are probably looking for an S3 bucket.

Comment: easiest is to host a pointer file in an S3 bucket (or where-ever your website is) that contains the URL of the HLS asset. You'll need to ensure it's not cached for too long if the asset will change frequently. I assume `Ooyala` is doing more for you that just hosting the asset though, so have you thought of other consequences of the change?

Answer (score 0):

I've built many apps on the devices you've listed. Some clients have decided to use an external config (json or xml) that each of the apps load on startup. Ultimately it is the equivalent of an API response. You can employ some cache busting during the request for the file to make sure you always get the latest. You can choose to host that file anywhere you want...